# Analyze of RNN vs CNN vs NN results in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have large labaled dataset. Each row contain `863` tokenized words. I am trying to verify which type of `NN` would be best for analyzing such dataset.
I have prepared 3 models:

CNN:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1, 32, input_length=863),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32, 5, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01)),
        tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
```

Simple flat NN:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1, 32,input_length=863),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

and RNN:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1, 32,input_length=863),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, activation='relu', return_sequences=True),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, activation='relu', ),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
```

`CNN` and `NN` are giving promising results with around 98% accu (possible overfitting) while `RNN` is getting only around 65% accu. It is worth to mention that epoch of RNN least somewhere around 10min while CNN and NN only 1 min.

How can I make RNN perform better?

Comment: just remove the FC layers from RNN. Also, make sure all the models have similar number of parameters, otherwise, the comparison is useless.

Comment: By FC You mean dense? I wanted each model to be similarly deep with layers.no=6 in scope of RNN only 2 middle layers of LSTM are going to be enough?

Answer (score 0):

**2 questions asked: why RNN is slower to train, why it doesn't reach good accuracy**

**answers**:

1. LSTM layers are highly complicated, and hence, complicated to train. if you have any GPU in hand (or google colab) i strongly suggest using `tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM`, this implementation makes huge difference in case of training time.
2. Stacking LSTM layers is not a very good practice (it is good in some special cases), hence make it one LSTM layer and use more units (ex. 64). This way you might get better performace. Other parameters might give better performance (like removing 2 dense layer after the LSTM layer as mentioned in the comments) but it is highly dependent to your data.

Comment: Doesn't TensorFlow 2 automatically use `CuDNNLSTM` If you have a GPU and CUDA installed?

Comment: from the time you gave, it didn't, i don't know the problem you have, but it is safe to use the `CuDNNLSTM` layer to see if there is any problem

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, RNN networks should perform *relatively* better on natural language data as they are superior to other NN networks at capturing long-term dependencies ––something that is seen commonly in textual data. However, if you are not obtaining the accuracy that you'd expect; there might be some hints to get improved. Although as you might have known, getting the highest accuracy on training data does not mean that the model is superior or so, but it definitely means that you are overfitting on training data, so you should normally worry when you get 100% accuracy on training data.

Some tips that you get the RNN network improved:

1. First and foremost, if possible, get more training data.
2. Hyperparameter tuning: play around with the hyperparameters of the model such as: learning rate, optimizer, number of hidden nodes, number of layers, and etc. Theoretically speaking, there should be some *optimal* hyperparameters by which you can get the highest accuracy. All you need is to experiment with different settings to examine which one works better for your task.

As for the training time, RNNs are being trained slowly because of their *recurrent* nature; a single RNN network cannot be parallelized to reduce the training time since each cell in the network does need the output from the previous cell for the computations. So cells will have to wait until their precursors are done with the computations, thereafter will run with the output of their precursor.